# Why the replication in Memgraph?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

What’s the major reason for Memgraph to support replication if it’s Cloud ready? What are the benefits? I've also seen that both Azure and AWS support replication as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out replication is a general concept, but the implementation is quite specific for a given system.

Memgraph implements a custom high-performance storage engine. A custom implementation of replication on top of the mentioned storage engine is required to properly support replicating data (to be correct, performant, etc.).

Of course, it’s possible to use Cloud services to backup data from Memgraph in various ways, but that has limitations when it comes to backup all data and the system’s availability.